# How can I get 2 overlapping meshes align their UV patterns?

Tags: uv

I have a character with a shirt top and a coat over it and I need the UV textures of both clothing to have the same UV coordinates at the same place on the body, to align as an overlap. In other words, if the coat was semi opaque the pattern position on the coat would be perfectly aligned with the pattern on the shirt.

Is there a way to assign one mesh no matter the different density or different orientation of the seams to align to the proximity UV coordinates of another mesh?

I need to apply this to existing mesh.